# CSS background image border

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
td.back {
    background:#000 url('0.jpg');
        }
```

How do I make the background image look like `<img border="4" src="0.jpg"/>`

Any ideas?

Html code:

```
<table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="back"><img src="gif1.gif"/></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
td.back {
    background:#000 url('0.jpg');
    border: 4px solid #000;
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ER4LB/
Or you can choose other options for border in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
    td.back {
        border-image:url('0.jpg');
        border: 4px solid #000;
}​
```

Comment: post your html relating to this

Comment: @Soner so what i'm understanding is you want an image as your border, but also a border around that?